# What is the maximum NFS exports possible in Linux?

Tags: linux, nfs, centos7

What is a definitive number for the maximum NFS4 exports possible in Linux? I'll be specific, Centos 7. (which is Kernel 3.10)

My searches are turning up numbers from 100-800 (mounted) exports possible and the limit seems to be tied to available ports. But the information is also relative to much older kernel versions. I'm wondering if there is a way to:

1. Determine the maximum exports possible
2. Adjust anything to increase it if the maximum possible is not sufficient for a particular use case.